# Translation of "the reason why ..."

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

> The reason why he didn't come to the party was that it rained.

Is it possible to translate the part "the reason why" directly with "la raison que"?

> (a) La raison qu'il n'est pas venu à la fête était qu'il a plu.

Or do I need to use "la raison pour laquelle" or "la raison pourquoi" instead?

> (b) La raison pour laquelle il n'est pas venu à la fête était qu'il a plu.
>
> (c) La raison pourquoi il n'est pas venu à la fête était qu'il a plu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) and (c) are very broken and incorrect French.

"The reason why..." doesn't translate to *La raison pourquoi...* but *La raison pour laquelle...*

> La raison pour laquelle il n'est pas venu à la fête est qu'il a plu.

To stay closer to "The reason that...", you might have said the ponderous:

> La raison qui l'a conduit à ne pas venir à la fête est qu'il a plu.

Simpler ways to tell it might be:

> Il n'est pas venu à la fête parce qu'il a plu.
>
> À cause de la pluie, il n'est pas venu à la fête.
>
> Parce qu'il pleuvait, il n'est pas venu à la fête.